# What is pi factorial?

Tags: factorial, pi

Anybody here know how to calculate pi factorial? Pi isn't an integer, or a rational number, so I don't know how to do it. Can anyone please tell me what it equals to?

Comment: It doesn't exist because factorial is only defined for non-negative integers. However, you may want to read up on the [Gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html).

Comment: It equals to $7.18808272898$. Use Gamma function.

Comment: Have you googled "pi factorial"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the gamma function which is a generalization of the factorial. Search for $\Gamma(z)$ . Check this link for your calculation. http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gamma%28pi%29&x=0&y=0

Comment: thanks! I will search that up!

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I would consider this a valid answer, except I would prefer adding a reference to the gamma function.

Comment: This is a valid answer, however, it could do with some expanding.

Comment: Thanks I forgot to paste the link

Comment: The gamma function is defined as $\Gamma(z+1)=z!$ if $z \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence, $\Gamma(\pi+1)$ should be evaluated instead of $\Gamma(\pi)$.